# cUrl to aiohttp multiform

Tags: python, curl, aiohttp

I have one curl command:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api-key.fusionbrain.ai/key/api/v1/text2image/run' \
--header 'X-Key: Key YOUR_KEY' \
--header 'X-Secret: Secret YOUR_SECRET' \
-F 'params="{
  \"type\": \"GENERATE\",
  \"generateParams\": {
    \"query\": \"sea\"
  }
}";type=application/json' \
--form 'model_id="4"'
```

It work in cli. But I need to make async request in Python.

My code:

```
headers = {"X-Key": f"Key {api_key}", "X-Secret": f"Secret {secret_key}", "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}
params = {
    "type": "GENERATE",
    "numImages": 1,
    "width": 1024,
    "height": 1024,
    "generateParams": {"query": "sea"},
}
data = {
    'model_id': (None, model_id),
    'params': (None, json.dumps(params), 'application/json')
}

async with ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
    async with session.post(url=self.gen_url, data=data) as response:
        result = await response.json()
        if response.ok:
            task_id = result["uuid"]
```

But I have error on service backend `Failed to parse multipart servlet request`
What am I doing wrong?

Sync request work done:

params = {
"type": "GENERATE",
"numImages": images,
"width": width,
"height": height,
"generateParams": {
"query": f"{prompt}"
}
}

data = {
'model_id': (None, model),
'params': (None, json.dumps(params), 'application/json')
}

response = requests.post(self.URL + 'key/api/v1/text2image/run', headers=self.AUTH_HEADERS, files=data)

data = response.json()
return data['uuid']

Comment: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#formdata